# Linear congruences and least positive residue

Tags: linear-algebra

Write down a linear congruence (modulo 31) whose solution is congruent to 11^28 (mod 31), and hence determine the least positive residue of 11^28 (mod 31).

This is what I have done so far.
11^5≡ 6(mod 31)
11^28≡ (11^5)^5 x 11^3≡ 6^5 x 11^3≡ 10(mod 31)

But how do I formulate a linear congruence and solve it in the way they are suggesting?

Comment: But I was meant to find the linear congruence first so how would I do it the other way round? I think I'm meant to use Fermat's little theorem somehow?

Comment: Perhaps I should have said that the first part of the question was solve 11x ≡ 1 (mod 31). Explain why the solution of this congruence is equal to the least positive residue of 11^29 (mod 31). Can I use this somehow?

Comment: If you have precisions you want to add to your question, you should add them to the body of the question, not as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Fermats little theorem states that

$$11^{30}\equiv 1 (mod\ 31)$$

So, the equation

$$121x\equiv 1 (mod 31)$$

must have the same solution as

$$x\equiv11^{28} (mod\ 31)$$

If you want to make two steps, you proceed as follows :

$$x\equiv11^{29} (mod 31)$$

leads to

$$11x\equiv 1(mod 31)$$

which has solution 17.

So

$$11^{29}\equiv 17 mod 31$$

So you get

$$11y\equiv 17 (mod 31)$$

with $y\equiv 11^{28} (mod 31)$

which has solution 10.

Comment: You can also make two steps and first take $11^{29}$ and 11x. The idea is the same.

Comment: How do you move from the first line to the second? How do you introduce the x? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Also 11x≡1 (mod 31) has solution x≡ 17 (mod 31)????

Comment: I did not move from line 1 to 2. I started with the observation that $11^{30}\equiv1 (mod31)$. Then I considered $x\equiv11^{28} (mod 31)$ and multiplied it with $11^2=121$ to get the second line.

Comment: To answer your second question : Simply continue solving $11x\equiv17(mod31)$ to get the result 10.

Comment: But how do you get x≡10 (mod 31) from 121x≡1 (mod 31)?

Comment: First of all, reduce 121 mod 31, which gives 28, modulo 31 the same as -3. So, you have $-3x\equiv1 (mod 31)$, which gives the result 10 easily.

Comment: Ahhhhh I'm with you!!!!!! Thank you soooo much :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By $\mu$Fermat, $\,{\rm mod}\ 31\!:\ 11^{30}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv  11^{28}\equiv \dfrac{1}{11^2}\equiv \dfrac{-30}{-3}\equiv 10$